# Conductor of a ring extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-verification

Consider the rings $A:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}^{\times}x$ and $B:=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. I am working on something where

> I need to find a relation between $A/\mathfrak{c}$ and $B/\mathfrak{c}$, where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the conductor.

I rewrite $A = \mathbb{C}[y]+xy\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Clearly the conductor is $(xy)$. Thus $A/\mathfrak{c}\cong\mathbb{C}[y]$ and $B/\mathfrak{c}\cong\mathbb{C}[x]+\mathbb{C}[y]$. Is this correct?

Comment: In your second form of $A$, you are missing $x^2$ and higher powers. Or was the first formulation intended to exclude all polynomials that are purely in $x$?

Comment: @YACP $A$ is indeed the set of polynomials that don't contain terms of the form $cx$ where $c\in \mathbb{C}$. I don't see how $A$ is different from $\mathbb{C}[y] + xy\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. For the element $0$ that you mention $0 \in \mathbb{C}[y]\subset \mathbb{C}[y] + xy\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Comment: @YACP I know that something is not right because $B/\mathfrak{c}$ should be a subring and $\mathbb{C}[x]+\mathbb{C}[y]$ is not a ring. But how is it wrong? It seems to me that $B/\mathfrak{c}$ gives the set of polynomials that don't have terms divisible by $xy$.

Comment: @LutzL, I see. You are right. $A$ cannot be written in the second form.

Comment: You can correct this by including the second term. Or write $A=\mathbb C[y]+x^2\mathbb C[x,y]+xy\mathbb C[x,y]$.

Comment: @LutzL , that is true but my aim for rewriting $A$ in a different way was to be able to find the conductor ideal in an easy way. That notation is not helpful that way. Do you have any idea on how to find it?

Comment: Well, both $x^2$ and $y$ are in the conductor. Shouldn't a first guess be $\mathfrak c=(x^2,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is the ring of polynomials $f\in\mathbb C[x,y]$ without terms in $x$, that is, $A=\mathbb C[x^2,x^3,y,xy]$. We have $A[x]=B$. An element $a\in A$ is in the conductor iff $ax\in A$. It's obvious now that $$\mathfrak c=\{a\in A: a(0,0)=0\}$$ and this is nothing but $(x^2,x^3,y,xy)$.

I don't know what relation are you expecting between $A/\mathfrak c$ and $B/\mathfrak c$, but $A/\mathfrak c\simeq\mathbb C$ and $B/\mathfrak c\simeq\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: Isn't $A/\mathfrak c\cong\mathbb C$ (via $a\mapsto a(0,0)$)?

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Of course! It was a mistake in the description of the generators of conductor as an ideal of $A$ (which are not the same as for the ideal in $\mathbb C[x,y]$, that is, $x^2$ and $y$). Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: YACP: Ah, that possibility didn't cross my mind, good catch.